# How to retrieved constraint violation messages if stored in different "ValidationMessages.properties" and which contain in different eclipse plugin

Tags: validation, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I am using hibernate validation framework in eclipse based (RCP) project.
I am having a different kind of plug-in in application like say

- Plugin A
- Plugin B
- Validation Plugin

"Plugin A" and "Plugin B" contains POJO classes and annotated with validation and I want constraint violation messages are retrieved from message descriptors (ValidationMessages.properties).

"Validation Plugin" contains jar required for "Hibernate Validation Framework" and API that we customized to support SWT widget validation.

I don't want to put my ValidationMessages.properties in this plugin every plugin should have there ValidationMessages.properties which contain messages specific to that POJO contains in that plugin.

But my constraint violation messages are retrieved from message descriptors only if I put my ValidationMessages.properties in Validation Plugin because it contains jar and its class loader only looks bundle in this plug-in only.

How can I distribute my ValidationMessages.properties in every plugin and my constraint violation messages are resolve from there bundle ??

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve this goal by implementing a custom resource bundle locator (see the HV [reference docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-resource-bundle-locator)).

More specifically, you'd create a custom implementation similar to the existing `AggregateResourceBundleLocator` one, which merges the resource bundles from the different modules of your application. For that you'd likely have to pass the bundle loaders of the different modules to that locator so it can obtain the resource bundles from them.